# Why do I receive a warning error when passing an array

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-select

I receive the following warning notice when passing an array from the HTML to the PHP:

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in (.../post2.php on line 68)

Here's where the data are captured in the input2.php file:

```
<td>
<select name="adult_fn_list[]" size="3" multiple="multiple">
<?php 
    $adult_sql = "SELECT first_name FROM member 
                    WHERE family_fkey = 34 
                    AND member_type = 'Adult' 
                    ORDER BY prim_key";
    $res=mysqli_query($link, $adult_sql) or die (mysqli_error($link));
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
    echo"<option value=".$row['first_name'].">".$row['first_name']."</option>";
?>
</select>
</td>
```

Here's line 68 in the post2.php code

```
$adult_fn_list = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST[adult_fn_list]);
```

I don't know why I'm receiving the warning notice.  When I print the array and elements out, they appear fine.  The following code:

```
print "The value of the adult_fn_list is: ";
print_r($_POST['adult_fn_list']);
print "<br /><br />The value of each individual element is: <br />";
Foreach ( $_POST['adult_fn_list'] as $SelectedFN )
    print ($SelectedFN . "<br />");
exit;
```

Produces the following results:

```
The value of the adult_fn_list is: Array ( [0] => Leonard [1] => Julia )

The value of each individual element is:
Leonard
Julia
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are posting HTML array: name="adult_fn_list[]", not a string. Therefore you can't pass it to mysqli_real_escape_string().

Comment: Thanks Greg.  I changed line 68 to: $adult_fn_list = $_POST[adult_fn_list]; and it worked fine.
If that list is coming from a database column, should I try to find a way to use mysqli to escape the data?

Comment: You have to expand the values into separate placeholders in your query and bind those. Even better would be to stop using low-level `mysqli` and use an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent) to handle this for you. They make it much easier to manage these sorts of relationships.